# Create new column if first letter is a specific letter in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Consider the following data in R:

```
d <- data.frame(a = c("E5","E5","E5","E5"),
                b = c("011","012","013","111"))
```

I want to add a new column that is equal to "A5" if the first letter in column b is 0 excerpt "013". That is, I want the following table:

```
    a   b    c  
1   E5  011  A5
2   E5  012  A5
3   E5  013
4   E5  111
```

How do I do that in R?

Comment: Maybe try: `d$c <- ifelse(substr(d$b, 1, 1) == "0" & d$b != "013", "A5", "")`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> d
   a   b
1 E5 011
2 E5 012
3 E5 013
4 E5 111
> transform(d, c = ifelse(str_detect(d$b, '^01[^3]'), 'A5',''))
   a   b  c
1 E5 011 A5
2 E5 012 A5
3 E5 013   
4 E5 111   
>
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[substr(b, 1, 1) == 0 & b != '013', c := 'A5']
```

-output

```
d
#    a   b    c
#1: E5 011   A5
#2: E5 012   A5
#3: E5 013 <NA>
#4: E5 111 <NA>
```